# How to make table of PDF 100% width for datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a table that I'm saving as a pdfHtml5 in datatable. I'm trying to make the table full width but I have been unsuccessful. How can I make my table 100% width using styles for my pdfHtml5?

```
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                  {
                      extend: 'collection',
                      text: '<div class="image"><img src="/Asset/Image/Capture.jpg" alt="" /></div>',
                      autoClose: true,
                      buttons: [{
                          extend: 'pdfHtml5', text: 'Download PDF Document', className: 'pdfdoc', title: podTitle, message: pod.data.pod_description_text + "\n" + "\n" + printDate, customize: function (doc) {
                              doc.defaultStyle.alignment = 'left';
                              doc.styles.tableHeader.alignment = 'left';
                              doc.styles.message = {
                                  alignment: 'center'
                              }
                                    doc.styles.table = {
                                  alignment: 'center',
                                  width: '100%',
                              }

                              /*doc.content[1].table.widths = Array(doc.content[1].table.body[0].length + 1).join('*').split('');*/
                              doc.pageMargins = [ 80, 20, 80, 20 ];

                          }
                      }, { extend: 'excel', text: 'Download Excel Document', className: 'exceldoc' },
                      ]
                  }
                ]
            });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By further extending pdfHtml5, you can instruct the pdfmake library, used by the Buttons extension, to use 100% width. The DataTables forum has a [post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/89764/#Comment_89764) with the required code:

```
var tbl = $('.dTable');
var settings={};
settings.buttons = [
    {
        extend:'pdfHtml5',
        text:'Export PDF',
        orientation:'landscape',
        customize : function(doc){
            var colCount = new Array();
            $(tbl).find('tbody tr:first-child td').each(function(){
                if($(this).attr('colspan')){
                    for(var i=1;i<=$(this).attr('colspan');$i++){
                        colCount.push('*');
                    }
                }else{ colCount.push('*'); }
            });
            doc.content[1].table.widths = colCount;
        }
    }
];
$('.dTable').dataTable(settings);
```

Note that if you just copy the customize portion of the code above, you must replace `tbl` by `"#myTable"` or something similar.

See also the related GitHub [ticket](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/344), including another [implementation](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/344#issuecomment-339684840) (which may or may not be out-of-date).

Answer (score 0):

I use this and works for me. Good luck.

```
{
    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    charset: 'utf-8',
    title:tableOptions.title.toUpperCase(),
    orientation: 'landscape',
    text: '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> PDF',
    exportOptions: {
        columns: [1,2,3,4]
    },
    customize: function(doc) {
        doc.content.splice( 0, 0, {
            margin: [ 7, 0, 0, -45 ],
            width: 85,
            height: 55,
            alignment: 'right',
            image: 'base64...'
        });

        let downloadDate=`${moment(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('DD-MM-YYYY')}`;
        let downloadTime=`${moment(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}`.slice(11,16);
        
        doc.content.splice( 2, 0, {
            alignment: 'left',
            fontSize:12,
            margin: [ 0, 0, -10, 20 ],
            color:"#003d66",
            text:`${downloadDate} / ${downloadTime} Hrs`
        });

        doc.defaultStyle.alignment = 'center';
        doc.defaultStyle.color = '#666';

        doc.styles.title.color="#00c4cc";
        doc.styles.title.alignment="left";
        doc.styles.title.fontSize=14;

       
        if(doc.content[3].table.body[0]){
            let columns=doc.content[3].table.body[0].length;
            let widths=[];

            for (let i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                widths.push(`${99/columns}%`)
            }

            doc.content[3].table.widths = widths;
        }

        doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize=12;
        doc.styles.tableHeader.fillColor="#003d66";
        doc.styles.tableBodyOdd.margin =[5, 5, 5, 5];
        doc.styles.tableBodyEven.margin = [5, 5, 5, 5];
    }
},
```